# Readonly reference type 's pointer can move after GC compress and move in .NET?

Tags: c#, pointers, reference, readonly

We all know that a `readonly` reference type variable's reference can't change, but the GC can change it. What happens when the GC changes the `readonly` type's pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking what happens when the GC moves the variable of readonly type

Then answer is nothing happens. GC moves the position as it normally does. That's all

For GC moving a non readonly type is same as moving a readonly type. ReadOnly and nonReadOnly concepts are for programmers not GC

Answer (score 0):

Readonly is not actually readonly... for example, reflection can change readonly fields. So this is then no different than **any other** reference (since GC is part of the VM, and much stronger than reflection).

Changing the value of string.Empty is always good for a giggle... (cough, I'd never do that, cough)

Answer (score 0):

First off, `readonly` references can be reassigned inside constructors. As for the GC moving pointers around, it's nothing special than what happens to other normal pointers, except user code can't change what they point to.

Essentially `readonly` only prevents YOU from changing the reference, not preventing the runtime to do what it's supposed to do.